# eliminating notifications duplicates

Tags: python, django, notifications

I'm trying to create notifications like facebook has. Everything works all right but I have duplicates. For instance, action = like, url = post/1 I want to get all notifications with status = 1 - unread and eliminate duplicates where action and url are the same. You can find code below I have such error:

error: 'list index out of range' in

`if n_dup[i]['url'] == n_dup[j]['url'] and n_dup[i]['action'] == n_dup[j]`

```
def recieve_notification(request):
    t = loader.get_template('notifications.html')
    nots = Notification.objects.filter(recipent=request.user, status=1, pub_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=3))
    n_dup = [] #list of notifications with duplicates
    for n in nots:
        n_dup.append({'id':n.id, 'url':n.url, 'action':n.action})

    i = len(n_dup)-1
    j = len(n_dup)-1    
    while j>=0:
        while i>=0: 
            if n_dup[i]['url'] == n_dup[j]['url'] and n_dup[i]['action'] == n_dup[j]['action'] and i is not j:  
                del n_dup[i]
            i-=1
        j-=1
        out_n = []      
        for n in n_dup:
            n_id = n['id']  
        out_n.append(Notification.objects.get(id=n_id)) 

    c = RequestContext(request, {'notifications':out_n, 'notifications_count':len(out_n)})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))`
```

Maybe you are in knowledge of better way to code all this stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first iteration of both loops, `j == i == len(n_dup)-1`, so `n_dup[i] == n_dup[j]`. It is considered a duplicate and is remove. On the second iteration, you'll try to access `n_dub[len(n_dup)-1]` which doesn't exist any more, because you removed it.

---

If I may suggest an alternative approach, lets be lazy and have python do the duplicate detection for us :

```
class Notification:
    def __init__(self, id, url, action):
        self.id = id
        self.url = url
        self.action = action

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.url == other.url and self.action == other.action

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.url) ^ hash(self.action)


unique_notifications = {Notification(n.id, n.url, n.action) for n in nots}
```

We define a notification object with a way to compare it and compute a hash (this is needed to put it in a set), and create a set of the notifications. A set never contains duplicate, so you can now iterate over the set !

You can also add this methods to your notification object and use it directly. You would then write :

```
out_n = set(Notification.objects.filter(...))
```

Bonus : the algorithm used by the set to remove duplicate is much more efficient than the one you where using.